# How to display a registry key(s) in a text box C#

Tags: c#, textbox, registry, startup

I am having trouble displaying all the registry keys in the startup section for Windows. I want to display all of the registry keys that tell programs to startup in a text box. I have been able to create a directory listing for the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, but I can't manage to narrow it down to the keys listed in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`  directory. Here is my code:

```
TreeNode localMachineNode = new TreeNode(Registry.LocalMachine.Name);
string[] localMachineSubKeys = Registry.LocalMachine.GetSubKeyNames();
foreach (string key in localMachineSubKeys)
{
    TreeNode node = new TreeNode(key, 0, 1);
}
```

If there is a better way to do this, i'd love to hear about it. Mind you, that is only part of my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [OpenSubKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9f66s0a.aspx) to open a key using a path:

```
var runs = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
   @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run");

var valueNames = runs.GetValueNames();

var values = new List<object>();
foreach (var valueName in valueNames)
{
    values.Add(runs.GetValue(valueName));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

```
var keys = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine
    .OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run")
    .GetSubKeyNames();
```

Comment: How can i display this in a list box? I tried doing listBox1.text = (keys); which does not work. I am using C# 2008. Thanks!

Comment: ok so it 'does not work'; in what way? What does the compiler tell you? What *Type* is key? What *Type* is listBox1.Text? Do you  really want to set the listBox1.Text property or add the values to a collection on the list box? I'll leave the rest to you :-) [I'm not trying to be difficult, teach a man to fish & all that]

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'string' That is the compiler error. I have a blank program open with a button and text box. The button's code is what you pasted above plus textBox1.Text = (keys); I have no other code in the program as I was trying to debug it separately. Also my goal is to list all registry keys in the run directory so users know everything that is starting up if that helps. I know I am a beginner/noob so don't worry about constructive criticism, if anything I need it. Thanks!